# HibernateQueryException: Expected positional parameter count, but query w/o parameter

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

during execution query i received error `Expected positional parameter count: 1, actual parameters: []` my query not have any parameters, **BUT** query contains **?** as value.

code

```
session.createSQLQuery(sql).list()
```

sql

```
SELECT file.name as `NAME` FROM film WHERE film.name IN ('You say "How I can make it? We' ..."');
```

**EDIT**

it also reproduced if search by name that contains **?** and **'**

```
SELECT file.name as `NAME` FROM film WHERE film.name IN ('?'')
```

How I can fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: @Unknown root cause in **'** with **?**

Answer (score 2):

Should work

```
String[] values= {"You say \"How I can make it? We' ...\""};
String sql = "SELECT file.name as `NAME` FROM film WHERE film.name IN (:values)";
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.setParameterList("values", values);
```

and then

```
query.list();
```

Comment: query generated dynamic, i can't handle value into `IN`

Comment: Then your code has SQL injection. Suppose I pass the name variable as **'); DROP table users;** Will your query drop the table?

Comment: no, because it value was into IN and occurred sql exception